# Apex Trigger was created for an Email attchment indicator - it's firing off assignment rules - why?

Tags: apex, assignment-rules

Currently we are using the Case object in Salesforce for our Customer Support Team.  They have the Salesforce Outlook Connector installed on their PC's.  Many times they have a case that they will add an email to it.  Some of those emails have pictures that explain the problem.

We want a "Attachment Indicator" to say the email has an attachment on it.  We created an APEX trigger that automatically updates this custom field. The issue is that when it's updated it's firing off the assignment rules again, which it should not be.

Below is the APEX Trigger:

```
trigger AttachmentTrigger on Attachment (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {

//This trigger has to go and update the Number of Activities field on Case after a task is Created or Updated or Deleted or after undeleted.

//Before events
//if(trigger.isBefore){
/*if(trigger.isInsert){

}
if(trigger.isUpdate){

}
if(trigger.isDelete){

}*/
//}

//After Events
if(trigger.isAfter){

if(trigger.isInsert){
AttachmentUtility.getCheckforAttachment(Trigger.new);
}
if(trigger.isUpdate){
AttachmentUtility.getCheckforAttachment(Trigger.new);
}
if(trigger.isDelete){
AttachmentUtility.getCheckforAttachment(Trigger.old); 
}
if(trigger.isUndelete){
AttachmentUtility.getCheckforAttachment(Trigger.new);
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the assignment rules run after triggers, you can find more info about that here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

Answer (score 1):

On the "why", your update of the flag will cause the assignment rules to run again.

To handle the problem, you could add this "formula evaluates to true" condition to each of your assignment rules (assuming your flag field is called Attachment_Indicator__c):

```
NOT(ISCHANGED(Attachment_Indicator__c))
```

Or add a first rule:

```
ISCHANGED(Attachment_Indicator__c)
```

that has the "Do Not Reassign Owner" checked in the "Step 3: Select the user or queue to assign the case to" part. (I assume but don't know that the rules will stop firing at that point.)

Comment: I was just about to type this out almost verbatim, though I think your second option makes a lot more sense. That should indeed stop the rules from firing.